# Uploading to Amazon S3 using cURL/libcurl

Tags: c++, windows, curl, amazon-s3, libcurl

I am currently trying to develop an application to upload files to an Amazon S3 bucket using cURL and c++. After carefully reading the S3 developers guide I have started implementing my application using cURL and forming the Header as described by the Developers guide and after lots of trials and errors to determine the best way to create the S3 signature, I am now facing a 501 error. The received header suggests that the method I'm using is not implemented. I am not sure where I'm wrong but here is the HTTP header that I'm sending to amazon:

```
PUT /test1.txt HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 29
Host: [BucketName].s3.amazonaws.com 
Date: [Date]
Authorization: AWS [Access Key ID]:[Signature] 
Expect: 100-continue
```

I have truncated the Bucket Name, Access Key ID and Signature for security reasons.

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong but I think that the error is generating because of the Accept and Transfer-Encoding Fields (Not Really Sure). So can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or why I'm getting a 501.

Comment: Solved: was missing an CURLOPT for the file size in my code and now everything is working perfectly

Answer (score -8, accepted):

Solved: was missing an CURLOPT for the file size in my code and now everything is working perfectly

Comment: What option?  How did the headers change?

Comment: I never understand why people respond with answers along the lines of "Oh I figured it out, but I'm not going to tell you what I did to solve it even though you spent time trying to help me out" elaborate on your solution, otherwise you are wasting peoples time.

Comment: This answer does not expose any explanation about the solution applied by the user Zaid Amir. It seems he's talking with himself.

Answer (score 7):

The game changed significantly since the question was asked, the simple authorization headers no longer apply, yet it is still feasible to perform with a UNIX shell script, as follows.

Ensure 'openssl' and 'curl' are available at the command line. TIP: double check the openSSL argument syntax as these may vary with different versions of the tool; e.g. openssl sha -sha256 ... versus openssl sha256 ...

Beware, a single extra newline or space character, else the use of CRLF in place of the NewLine char alone would defeat the signature. Note too that you may want to use content types possibly with encodings to prevent any data transformation through the communication media. You may then have to adjust the list of signed headers at several places; please refer to [AMAZON S3 API docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-auth-using-authorization-header.html) for the numerous conventions to keep enforced like alphabetical-lowercase ordering of header info used in hash calculations at several (redundant) places.

```
# BERHAUZ Nov 2019 - curl script for file upload to Amazon S3 Buckets
test -n "$1" || {
  echo "usage: $0 <myFileToSend.txt>"
  echo "... missing argument file ..."
  exit
}
yyyymmdd=`date +%Y%m%d`
isoDate=`date --utc +%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ`
# EDIT the next 4 variables to match your account
s3Bucket="myBucket.name.here"
bucketLocation="eu-central-1" 
s3AccessKey="THISISMYACCESSKEY123"
s3SecretKey="ThisIsMySecretKeyABCD1234efgh5678"

#endpoint="${s3Bucket}.s3-${bucketLocation}.amazonaws.com"
endpoint="s3-${bucketLocation}.amazonaws.com"

fileName="$1"
contentLength=`cat ${fileName} | wc -c`
contentHash=`openssl sha256 -hex ${fileName} | sed 's/.* //'`

canonicalRequest="PUT\n/${s3Bucket}/${fileName}\n\ncontent-length:${contentLength}\nhost:${endpoint}\nx-amz-content-sha256:${contentHash}\nx-amz-date:${isoDate}\n\ncontent-length;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date\n${contentHash}"
canonicalRequestHash=`echo -en ${canonicalRequest} | openssl sha256 -hex | sed 's/.* //'`

stringToSign="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n${isoDate}\n${yyyymmdd}/${bucketLocation}/s3/aws4_request\n${canonicalRequestHash}"

echo "----------------- canonicalRequest --------------------"
echo -e ${canonicalRequest}
echo "----------------- stringToSign --------------------"
echo -e ${stringToSign}
echo "-------------------------------------------------------"

# calculate the signing key
DateKey=`echo -n "${yyyymmdd}" | openssl sha256 -hex -hmac "AWS4${s3SecretKey}" | sed 's/.* //'`
DateRegionKey=`echo -n "${bucketLocation}" | openssl sha256 -hex -mac HMAC -macopt hexkey:${DateKey} | sed 's/.* //'`
DateRegionServiceKey=`echo -n "s3" | openssl sha256 -hex -mac HMAC -macopt hexkey:${DateRegionKey} | sed 's/.* //'`
SigningKey=`echo -n "aws4_request" | openssl sha256 -hex -mac HMAC -macopt hexkey:${DateRegionServiceKey} | sed 's/.* //'`
# then, once more a HMAC for the signature
signature=`echo -en ${stringToSign} | openssl sha256 -hex -mac HMAC -macopt hexkey:${SigningKey} | sed 's/.* //'`

authoriz="Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=${s3AccessKey}/${yyyymmdd}/${bucketLocation}/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-length;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=${signature}"

curl -v -X PUT -T "${fileName}" \
-H "Host: ${endpoint}" \
-H "Content-Length: ${contentLength}" \
-H "x-amz-date: ${isoDate}" \
-H "x-amz-content-sha256: ${contentHash}" \
-H "${authoriz}" \
http://${endpoint}/${s3Bucket}/${fileName}
```

I must acknowledge that, for someone a bit involved in cryptography like me, the Amazon signature scheme deserves numerous critics:

- there's much redundancy in the information being signed,
- the 5 step HMAC cascade is almost inverting semantics between key seed and data where 1 step would suffice with proper usage and same security
- the last 12 characters of the secret key are useless here, because the significant key length of a SHA256 HMAC is ... 256 bits, hence 32 bytes, of which the first 4 always start with "AWS4" for just no purpose.
- overall AWS S3 API re-invents standards where a S/MIME payload would have done

Apologize for the critics, I was not able to resist. Yet acknowledge: it is working reliably, useful for many companies, and an interesting service with a rich API.

Comment: I was halfway to writing this thing out, then decided to search with one more set of keywords and found this answer. So far it's the closest I've gotten, though it does seem the signature scheme has changed again as Amazon is responding with 'The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.' Thank you for hacking this out for the rest of us!

Comment: "signature calculated does not match" indicates a discrepancy between the 'canonicalRequest' or 'stringToSign' and actual HTTP headers/data. Be very careful with file path (AWS3 only knows about bucket's PUT path) and also consider strictest alignment between request headers and their listings in both 'canonicalRequest' AND 'stringToSign'. Use curl -v (verbose) to see exact headers and paths in your HTTP request. Also, if you (e.g.) added content-type, the headers' listings in 'canonicalRequest' AND 'stringToSign' must be adjusted and 'normalized' as documented in their API docs in ref.

Comment: I've got the following error: from AWS "The authorization header is malformed; Invalid credential date. Date is not the same as X-Amz-Date". Here is the key/value for it: "x-amz-date: 20201025T020215Z"

Comment: I would think (but unsure) that a "Date" header is inserted when the submitting the HTTP request based on your local machine time zone and that this header value conflicts with the one date generated as x-amz-date... ensure too that you machine time is sufficiently aligned with official time.

Comment: `<Error><Code>InvalidRequest</Code><Message>Missing required header for this request: x-amz-content-sha256</Message`

Comment: That's explicit: look carefully to the script, the missing header shall be built. So you very likely have some part of the script that doesn't execute as intended. Check the shell exec environment (notably the behavior of the echo command in your shell) and chase undersirable characters that may have slipped in. Add traces to exchanges with curl -v argument. Cascading crypto operations in a shell as above is brittle by nature.

Answer (score 6):

You could execute a bash file. Here is an example `upload.sh` script which you could just run as: `sh upload.sh yourfile`

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
bucket=YOUR_BUCKET
resource="/${bucket}/${file}"
contentType="application/x-itunes-ipa"
dateValue=`date -R`
stringToSign="PUT\n\n${contentType}\n${dateValue}\n${resource}"
s3Key=YOUR_KEY_HERE
s3Secret=YOUR_SECRET
echo "SENDING TO S3"
signature=`echo -en ${stringToSign} | openssl sha1 -hmac ${s3Secret} -binary | base64` 
curl -vv -X PUT -T "${file}" \
 -H "Host: ${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com" \
 -H "Date: ${dateValue}" \
 -H "Content-Type: ${contentType}" \
 -H "Authorization: AWS ${s3Key}:${signature}" \
 https://${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/${file}
```

more on: http://www.jamesransom.net/?p=58

http://www.jamesransom.net/?p=58

Comment: Thanks but this question was from five years ago and it is for Windows as the tag suggests.

Comment: On nix you can do `contentType="$(file -b --mime-type "$1")"`