# PUT file to S3 with presigned URL

Tags: java, curl, amazon-s3

I've been playing with Amazon S3 presigned URLs all night attempting to PUT a file.  I generate the presigned URL in java code.

```
    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials( accessKey, secretKey );
    client = new AmazonS3Client( credentials );
    GeneratePresignedUrlRequest request = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest( bucketName, "myfilename", HttpMethod.PUT);
    request.setExpiration( new Date( System.currentTimeMillis() + (120 * 60 * 1000) ));
    return client.generatePresignedUrl( request ).toString();
```

I then want to use the generated, presigned URL to PUT a file using curl.

```
curl -v -H "content-type:image/jpg" -T mypicture.jpg https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/myfilename?Expires=1334126943&AWSAccessKeyId=<accessKey>&Signature=<generatedSignature>
```

I assumed that, like a GET, this would work on a bucket which is not public (that's the point of presigned, right?)  Well, I got access denied on every attempt.  Finally out of frustration I changed the permission of the bucket to allow EVERYONE to write.  Of course, then the presigned URL worked.  I quickly removed the EVERYONE permission from the bucket.  Now, I don't have permission to delete the item that was uploaded into my bucket by my own self-pre-signed URL.  I [see now](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html) that I probably should have put a x-amz-acl header on what I uploaded.  I suspect I'll create several more undelete-able objects before I get that right.

This leads to a few questions:

- How can I upload with curl using PUT and a generated presigned URL?
- How can I delete the uploaded file and the bucket I created to test it with?

The end goal is that a mobile phone will use this presigned URL to PUT images.  I'm trying to get it going in curl as a proof of concept.

**Update:** I asked a question on the [amazon forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=91800). If an answer is provided there I'll put it as an answer here.

Comment: The amazon forums were as helpful as ever (meaning not a peep on my question) so I ended up having to work around this by uploading to my app and then having my app use the java api to send the image to S3.

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't use a pre signed POST? Perhaps they will work better, if for no other reason than they may have been more tested in the SDK, etc. I certainly was able to set the content type in a pre signed post using the ruby gem from amazon.

Comment: Their docs suggest PUT as the best way to put content. Despite that I did spend some time trying to get POST to work and it didn't work either. Again, I believe the problem is with the content-type that is being set, perhaps it is particular to the java SDK. Once I get the content in there (by any means) my pre-signed GET is working very well.  I've tried SDK 1.3.3 and 1.3.6. I know they are at 1.3.8 now but release notes didn't indicate any changes related to this issue.

Comment: Sugg: switch to header-based signature to PUT your file with curl, as explained at  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59295183/3784642

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is indeed a bit puzzling, I consider it to be a bug in the [AWS SDK for Java](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/) (see below) - but first and foremost, the following [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) command will upload your file as such (assuming an updated pre-signed URL of course):

```
curl -v -T mypicture.jpg https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/myfilename?Expires=1334126943&AWSAccessKeyId=<accessKey>&Signature=<generatedSignature>
```

That is, I've excluded the `Content type` header, which yields `application/octet-stream` (or `binary/octet-stream`) as a result, which is obviously not desired; thus, further digging had been order.

### Background / Analysis

Pre-signed URLs for PUT (and DELETE as well as HEAD) requests to [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) are known to work in principle, not the least evidenced in related questions on this site (see e.g. my answer to [Upload to s3 with curl using pre-signed URL (getting 403)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9085141/45773)).

The facilitated [Query String Request Authentication Alternative](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationQueryStringAuth) is documented to use the following *pseudo-grammar that illustrates the query string request authentication method*:

```
StringToSign = HTTP-VERB + "\n" +
    Content-MD5 + "\n" +
    Content-Type + "\n" +
    Expires + "\n" +
    CanonicalizedAmzHeaders +
    CanonicalizedResource;
```

It does include the `Content-Type` header, and (as you already discovered) this has been the missing piece in some documented cases, see e.g. the AWS team response to [GetPreSignedURL with PUT request](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=244858#244858), yielding a working pre-signed URL once added.

This is easy to achieve with the [AWS SDK for .NET](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/) indeed, which provides the convenience method [GetPreSignedUrlRequest.WithContentType](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_S3_Model_GetPreSignedUrlRequest_WithContentType.htm) to do just that:

> Sets the ContentType property for this request. This property defaults
>   to "binary/octet-stream", but if you require something else you can
>   set this property.

Accordingly, extending the respective sample [Upload an Object Using Pre-Signed URL - AWS SDK for .NET](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjectPreSignedURLDotNetSDK.html) as follows yields a working pre-signed URL with content type, that can be uploaded via *curl* as expected (i.e. exactly as you attempted to):

```cs
    // ...
    GetPreSignedUrlRequest request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest();
    // ...
    request.WithContentType("image/jpg");
    // ...
```

Now, one would like to extend the semantically identical sample [Upload an Object Using Pre-Signed URL - AWS SDK for Java](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObjectDotNetSDK.html) in a similar fashion, but (as you've discovered already as well), there is no dedicated method to achieve this. This might just be a lacking convenience method though and could be achievable via [addRequestParameter()](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/GeneratePresignedUrlRequest.html#addRequestParameter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) or [setResponseHeaders()](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/GeneratePresignedUrlRequest.html#setResponseHeaders%28com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ResponseHeaderOverrides%29) eventually, e.g.:

```java
  // ...
  request.setExpiration( new Date( System.currentTimeMillis() + (120 * 60 * 1000) ));
  request.addRequestParameter("content-type", "image/jpg");
  return client.generatePresignedUrl( request ).toString();
  // ...
```

However, both method's documentation suggests other purposes, and it doesn't work indeed, i.e. they always yield the identical signature, no matter which content type is set like so (if any).

Debugging further into the SDKs reveals, that both provide a semantically similar core method to calculate the query string authentication according to the *pseudo-grammar* referenced above, see [buildSigningString()](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-net/blob/master/Amazon.S3/AmazonS3Client.cs#L6173) for .NET and [makeS3CanonicalString()](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/s3/internal/RestUtils.java#L57) for Java.

But the respective code in the Java version to *Add all interesting headers to a list, then sort them*, where *"Interesting" is defined as Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, and x-amz-* is never executed in fact, because there is indeed no method to provide these headers somehow, which are only available for class [DefaultRequest](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/DefaultRequest.html) and not class [GeneratePresignedUrlRequest](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/GeneratePresignedUrlRequest.html) used to initialize the former, which is used as input for calculating the signature in turn, see protected method [createRequest()](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.java#L2593).

Interestingly/Notably, the two methods to calculate the query string authentication in .NET vs. Java compose their input from an almost inverse combination of *header* vs. *parameter* sources on the call stack, which could hint on the cause of the Java bug, but obviously that might as well be just difficult to decipher, i.e. the internal architecture could differ significantly of course.

#### Preliminary Conclusion

There are two angles to this:

- The AWS SDK for Java is definitely lacking the convenience method for setting the content type, which might be a comparatively rare, but nonetheless obvious use case accounted for in other AWS SDKs accordingly - this is surprising, given its widespread use in AWS related backend services.
- Regardless, there seems to be something fishy with the way the *Query String Request Authentication* is implemented in comparison to the .NET version for example - again this is surprising, given it is a core functionality, however, this is still within the S3 model/namespace and thus might only be required by the respective uses cases above.

In conclusion, the only reasonable way to resolve this would be an updated SDK, so a bug report is in order - obviously one could as well duplicate/extend the SDK functionality to account for this special case separately (ideally in a way allowing to submit a pull request for the [aws-sdk-for-java project](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-java)), but getting this right in a compatible and maintainable way seems to be a bit tricky, thus is likely best done by the SDK maintainers themselves.

Comment: As of version 1.11.8 (I haven't dug into the diffs to see if/when this may have changed) GeneratePresignedUrlRequest extends AmazonWebServiceRequest which provides the method putCustomRequestHeader(String key, String value) for all of your custom header needs. This is how to add headers that the signing algorithm includes as "Interesting" internally. This does not appear to be (well?) documented. Also, you will need to manually include "x-amz-"... in your header names to add user defined metadata to the uploaded object.

Comment: As I just learnt the hard way the ContentType needs to match with whatever tools is actually doing the PUT request. In my case I was using Ajax and until I discovered this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2845487/2162886 it appeared that any calls to set the content type in the PreSignedURL would (naturally) fail. Hindsight is as they say 20/20 as this is likely painfully obvious and goes without saying but I would have appreciated it said! :)

Comment: The same proble with javascript SDK. You have to provide Content-Type manually for presidned url to work.

Comment: Url should be under double qoutes in curl command, because without it, the command won't work and aws will return some error.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem as well. We're already tracking when the file is uploaded on the backend, so our work around was to set the content type after the client uploads the file using the Rails app with a call to copy_from.